# PHP code in menu links

Tags: theming, hooks

One of many things I want to do in Drupal is to have

```
Hi: "User name"
```

link for /users page. (In the future I also want to have a control over visibility of menu tabs and their links depending on the logged user.)

Currently I have a quick, easy and relaxing solution - hacked page.tpl.php which works perfectly. Unfortunately I it is not a perfect (nor profesional) solution because the website will brake down as soon as I update the drupal core.

Is there any way of injecting php code into menu link/title without messing up the core?

I've been thinking about using translation module, menu module, and others but so far I have not been successful. I know that menus in drupal are designed to be static, but there must be a walk-around.

I know that menu_token can solve some of my problems but it does not work for me (when installed I have memory allocation issues in php server or crashing MYSQL).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured this out.
YES it is possible to have dynamic menus in Drupal.

You start by enabling dynamic access to menu item with the ['alter'] flag and hook_menu_link_alter(&$item).

```
function mycode_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
    if($item['menu_name'] == 'user-menu'){
        $item['options']['alter'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Note that menu_link_alter works on a menu item (not the whole menu) and needs to be trigered by editing and saving that item (for example disable->save->enable->save->).

Once the menu item is activated, I can use
hook_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map)

```
function mycode_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map){
    //drupal_set_message("Menu: ".$item['menu_name']." Item: ".$item['title']
    if($item['menu_name'] == 'user-menu'){
        global $user;
        $item['title'] = "Hi: $user->name";
    }
}
```

Other very useful thing you can do is to disable the menu link

```
$item['hidden'] = TRUE;
```

or (my favorite) change the links

```
[...];    
if($item['menu_name'] == 'main-menu'){
   switch ($item['title']){
       case "Home":
            $item['href'] = 'not/home/page';
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you hacked the page.tpl.php file which came installed with Drupal? I hope not. The way you do it (the Drupal way) is you place a copy of that file in your theme folder (`/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/templates`) instead, clear cache, and you're done - from now on Drupal will use your template. During any core upgrade you typically leave the `sites` folder in place and thus your hack, your theme, your everything stays intact.

As per PHP code in menu, I have seen that in [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu), but I haven't tested this particular feature.

As with any international site - it's advisable to first test any newly installed module against its i18n support before you test any other features.

Comment: Artur
I am working on a developed web site with a hacked core.
Because so far I did not manage to update the core without breaking the site I am redeveloping the hacks that were done and I want to do it properly (if possible).

Thanks for your hints, I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token)

> Menu Token module provides tokens, that could be used in title or in
>   path of menu items (links). For example, if you create a menu item
>   with path: "user/[current-user:uid]", the url will be changed "on fly"
>   to: "user/1" (assuming you are user 1).