# Adding a page to a menu with query parameters in the URL

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to add a page generated by CiviCRM to my menu. The pages url is 'civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=6'. I've added the link to the drupal menu manually, and it goes to the page, but that menu item isn't set to active and the active-trail class is not set to it's parent items.

I tried using the full URL and also tried created a module that added a hook_menu function to create a url without query parameters. The hook_menu callback would redirect to the path above.

How can I add that link to my menu, and have the active and active-trail classes set?

Comment: I am not sure if this would help. But have you tried http://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path

Comment: Yea, I was looking at that and http://drupal.org/project/menu_position, but no luck yet. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: it is due query parameters. use pathauto to change its path.

Comment: Pathauto works great, but unfortunately it wont allow patterns for CiviCRM pages.

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes, this has plagued me for years.  I cheat and use "Global Redirect Module" https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of making menus do whatever you want, including generating the menu link by php code whenever it is being viewed.

The details you can find in the answer below
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53531/12153